# I can't use "texture&dehaze" when I add a mask in LRC V13

Tags: photo-editing, adobe-lightroom, portrait

I have a portrait of a girl and I want to lower the texture only on her face so I added a mask but now I can't find options like dehaze and texture.
I see people doing it all the time on youtube..
I use LRC V13 which should be the most comprehensive
how can I fix this please?

Answer (score 0):

It is there, just way down the list.  The problem is that it's in a different location from when you are in the Develop Basic mode. When you are in Masking, the arrangement of the controls changes.

Make sure you are in Develop mode, and in Masking

Scroll down the list until you find it under Effects. The controls are there.

[image]